# Node delete performance issue

Tags: nodes

I am using below code to delete all unregistered users node.
But it takes very long time to execute node_delete function.I have around 5000 records of users in node table.
How can I improve the performance of node_delete() function?

```
$query_node = db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM node n,status s WHERE s.entity_id = n.nid  AND type = 'employees' AND s.field_employee_status_value = '2' AND n.status = '1'");               
$result_node = $query_node->fetchAll();

foreach($result_node as $node)
{
    $nid = $node->nid;
    // $node id , which you want to delete;
    node_delete($nid);                              
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two appropriate options:

1. Use [`node_delete_multiple`](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_delete_multiple/7) function instead of the `node_delete()`. I guess you need to do this only once, so this might be a faster solution if your server can execute the whole process at once (ie enough memory, not too many fields/modules, etc.).

   ```
   $query_node = db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM node n,status s WHERE s.entity_id = n.nid  AND type = 'employees' AND s.field_employee_status_value = '2' AND n.status = '1'");               
   $result_node = $query_node->fetchAll();

   $nids = array();
   foreach($result_node as $node) {
     $nids[] = $node->nid;
   }
   // Delete everything at once.
   node_delete_multiple($nids);
   ```
2. You can also use [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) with [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). You can filter the nodes based on what you need and then perform operations on all rows. This will process the deletion as a batch process. Downside is that you might need to install 2 additional modules if you don't have them already.

Comment: node_delete itself uses node_delete_multiple function inside of it.So first option will not work

Comment: Yup, that's right, just checked it. Could still count as a very minor performance improvement :) will remove the first option and leave the second one. There are others as well, but they might be overkill (e.g. custom module with your own batch process).

Comment: Wait. On a second thought, I should not have removed the first part - there is a difference when you are calling a function 5.000 times and when you call it once. Still a performance improvement and is relevant here.

Comment: I have to call node_delete_multiple in foreach loop right

Comment: Answer updated; you put all nids in an array and then call only once the `node_delete_multiple()` and pass it as an argument.

Comment: That worked with improvement in performance - Thank you!

Comment: Sure, glad it helped.